# Updating a field to empty string

Tags: soap-api, c#, enterprise

I'm trying to update a custom field. It's called `Name2` which is filled using the enterprise soap api.

Now I have an object where `Name2` is set to `__TEST__`. Now I want to update this field to contain only `` (=empty string).

Unfortunately this does not work There is also no Name2_Specified in the WSDL file. How to clear out the field programmatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Resetting Values to null**

To reset a field value to null, you add the field name to the fieldsToNull array in the sObject. You cannot set required fields (nillable is false) to null.

Source: 
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_update.htm